# Multiple String to dict conversion

Tags: dictionary

How do I create a dictionary from this string:
"John:23,Marc:24,Tim:43,Jake:21"

expected output:
dict = {"John":23,"Marc":24,"Tim":43,"Jake":21}
so then I can do:
sum(dict.values())

Thank you

Comment: what is the programming language of the question

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
>>> x = "John:23,Marc:24,Tim:43,Jake:21
>>> dict([y.split(':') for y in x.split(',')])
{'Tim': '43', 'John': '23', 'Jake': '21', 'Marc': '24'}
>>>
```